# How to transform to Map<String, Entity> in Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate

I have a table:

- email: varchar, unique
- name: varchar

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|      email          |       name       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|    a@gmail.com      |         a        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|    b@gmail.com      |         b        |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

And, a Class

```
Class A {
   private String email;
   private String name;
   // Set - Get
}
```

Until now, I must `query.list()` to get `List<A>`, after that I must loop to convert to `Map<String, A>`.

```
Key: a@gmail.com -> Value: A(email=a@gmail.com, name=a)
Key: b@gmail.com -> Value: A(email=b@gmail.com, name=b)
```

how to get `Map<String, A>` directly from Hibernate ?

======================== UPDATE ============================

Up to now, This is all that I know. It looks messing.

```
public Map<String, A> getMap(){

   Map<String, A> map = new HashMap<>();

   session.createNativeQuery("SELECT email, name FROM [my_table]")
          .setResultTransformer(
              new ResultTransformer() {
                  @Override
                  public Object transformTuple(Object[] tuple, String[] aliases) {
                      map.put(tuple[0].toString(), new A(tuple[0].toString(), tuple[1].toString()));
                      return null;
                  }

                  @Override
                  public List transformList(List collection) {
                      return new ArrayList<>();
                  }
              }
          ).list();

     return map;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You don't. `return query.getResultList().collect(Collectors.toMap(A::getEmail, Function.identity()))` is all you need.

Comment: I mean I want to improve performance when to get ```Map<String, A>```. I think, internally, Hibernate has a loop for creating ```List<A>``` from ResultSet and now, my loop will convert ```List<A>``` to ```Map<String, A>```. it looks quite slow. Is there any other way I don't need my loop to get ```Map<String, A>``` from ResultSet in Hibernate? By the way,  Is your code improve performance better my code? or it's only sugar syntax in java8?

Comment: That's just premature optimization. Storing elements in a list or a map is not where the time is spent. It's spent in IO and in the query execution by the database, and a tiny bit in creating the A instances from the result set. **If** you have a performance problem there, then start by measuring where it comes from, and then optimize that part. In 99% of the cases, that will mean tuning the database indices or the query. If you don't have any performance problem, then don't make up imaginary ones.

Comment: Yes, I see. My question is only technically. I want to know whether Hibernate has supported another way of this issue or not. Anyway, thanks for the reply.